# Interactive zmax for plotly heatmap?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, plotly, plotly-python

Is it possible to make the zmax setting for a plotly heatmap interactive?  I'm generating a heatmap in Jupyter Notebook with Python and it would be nice if the zmax could be changed directly on the plot by entering a new number in the colorbar, a slider bar, or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

- direct entry would require **dash**
- using just **plotly** you can have a menu of pre-defined values

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure(data=go.Heatmap(z=[[1, 20, 30], [20, 1, 60], [30, 60, 1]]))
fig.update_layout(
    updatemenus=[
        {
            "buttons": [
                {"label": str(v), "method": "restyle", "args": [{"zmin": 0, "zmax": v}]}
                for v in range(10, 60, 10)
            ]
        }
    ]
)
```

[image]